# How to fetch specific column in Drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, select, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to fetch one column which is (filename) in my table.

Below is my query:

```
$query = db_select('network_drive_listing','n');
$query
    ->fields('n', array('filename'))
  ->condition('n.network_drive_id',$id)
  ->condition('n.is_dir',0)
  ->orderBy('n.ndlistid');
    $results = $query->execute();

echo "<pre>".print_r($results)."</pre>"; die;
```

and my output looks like below:

```
             DatabaseStatementBase Object ( [dbh] => DatabaseConnection_mysql Object ( [needsCleanup:protected] => [target:protected] => default [key:protected] => default [logger:protected] => [transactionLayers:protected] => Array ( ) [driverClasses:protected] => Array ( [SelectQuery] => SelectQuery [InsertQuery] => InsertQuery_mysql [DatabaseSchema] => DatabaseSchema_mysql ) [statementClass:protected] => DatabaseStatementBase [transactionSupport:protected] => 1 [
```

I am trying to get one specific column, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a fetch method onto your result object. Ie.:

```
$results = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

Please have a read on these too:

- [function db_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_select/7.x)
- [Result sets](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/result-sets)

Comment: I did not have .install file in module, there is table in my database which I am trying to fetch, not having install file could cause this issue?